# Filter out array as per matching properties using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, dictionary, filter

I have a array with properties -

```
(5) [VectorNode, VectorNode, VectorNode, VectorNode, VectorNode]
0: VectorNode
id: "5:4"
name: "group_00"
x: (...)
y: (...)
__proto__: Object
1: VectorNode {id: "5:5"}
2: VectorNode {id: "5:6"}
3: VectorNode {id: "5:7"}
4: VectorNode {id: "5:8"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Not all VectorNodes will have the property name as *group_01*. I want to filter out only those VectorNodes whose name matches this regex -  "/_\d+/" which is basically any VectorNode with name - dsadsa_01, dgdfg_0, oopoo_0999

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use match() function which takes regex as argument

here is the link for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

So you can do something like this:

```
arrayOfVectorNodes.filter(_ => !!_.name.toLocaleLowerCase().match(yourRegex));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter your array by using array.filter() method

```
let x = [{name:"group_00"},{name:"group_01"},{name:"group_abc"}];

const regex = /_\d+/;

let y = x.filter(function({name})=>{

return regex.test(name)
})

console.log(y)
```